# Double click mouse action of TextBox is not allowed

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, inputbinding

I am trying to set the double click gesture of a text box in this way:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="MouseDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DobleClickCommand}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</Textbox>
```

But I get the error that the mouse action MOUSEDOUBLECLICK is not allowed.

I would like to bind it to the command in my view model.

Is input bindings the way to do it?

Comment: I don't see a [`MouseAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouseaction?view=netcore-3.1) for `MouseDoubleClick`.  Have you tried `LeftDoubleClick`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mouse binding is wrong, there is no `MouseDoubleClick`, use `LeftDoubleClick`. For a list of valid mouse actions, look in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouseaction?view=netcore-3.1#fields). If you want to execute the action for `MiddleDoubleClick` or `RightDoubleClick`, too, you can create separate mouse bindings for them to the same command.

```
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding TestingCommand}"/>
```

Alternatively, you can use `MouseAction` instead of a `Gesture`:

```
<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DobleClickCommand}"/>
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousebinding?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) recommends to use `Gesture` instead of `MouseAction`:

> When defining a MouseBinding in Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML), there are two ways to specify the MouseGesture. The first way to establish a MouseBinding in XAML is to define the Gesture attribute of the MouseBinding element, which enables a syntax to specify mouse actions and modifiers as a single string; for example, "CTRL+LeftClick". The second way is to define the MouseAction attribute of the MouseBinding element.

> In general, it is recommended that you use only the Gesture attribute from XAML, even if you do not specify modifiers; this avoids ambiguity, provides the most streamlined syntax, and provides the most straightforward representation for serialization.

On the [difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousebinding.gesture?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) between a [`MouseAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouseaction?view=netcore-3.1) and a `Gesture`:

> A MouseGesture is a MouseAction with or without a set of ModifierKeys. Unlike a KeyGesture, a MouseGesture does not need to have a modifier key associated with it.

Comment: A `MouseAction` is just an enumeration of all possible actions, like _left click_, _right click_ and so on. A `Gesture` however let's you define more than that, modifier keys, e.g. `Control+WheelClick`.